# Adding column based on other column

Tags: r

If I have a dataset called data.

I need to add a column based on this logic
0 if "gender" in data is 0 or 1 or 3;
1 if "gender" in data is 2

How can I create a code to add in?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `gender` would only take on the possible values 0, 1, and 2, we can try using `ifelse` as follows:

```r
data$flag <- ifelse(data$gender <= 1, 0, 1)
```

We can use `case_when()` from the `dplyr` library for finer grain control:

```r
data$flag <- case_when(
    gender %in% c(0, 1) ~ 0,
    gender == 2 ~ 1,
    # add other mappings here
    TRUE ~ NA
)
```

Comment: gender can be 3.

Comment: This does not change the values to 0 for data points equal 3. I would suggest to use `ifelse(data$gender == 2, 1, 0)`. This sets all values that are equal to 2 to 1 and everything else to 0.

Comment: @Nightqueen If the gender value be 3, then what should the output be?